# Regex to Match 5ABCDEXXX

Tags: python, regex

I have mobile numbers consisting of 9 digits.

**What I tried**

I have a regex to match this pattern `5ABCDEXXX`. A sample `582694666`.

```
.{5}(?!(\d)\1)\d(\d){3}
```

`5ABCDEXXX`:

- starts with `5`
- 4 different numbers `ABCDE`
- 3 similar numbers at the end `XXX`

My problem is that this regex will match any mobile number that has 3 repeated numbers despite their index. For example, the regex will also match `552728495` because it has 3 fives.

**What I want**

I want to remodify my regex to match this pattern only `5ABCDEXXX`. The three similar numbers should be at the end of the mobile number.

Comment: Sounds like you'd be better off not using RegEx for this and just iterating over the characters instead

Comment: The requirement to not have repeated digits in ABCDE is unclear and counterintuitive. Do you mean 512314777 should not match because 1 is repeated? What about 512354777? What about 512374777?

Comment: "4 different numbers ABCDE" should that be "**5** different numbers ABCDE"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^5(\d)(?!\1)(\d)(?!\1|\2)(\d)(?!\1|\2|\3)(\d)(?!\1|\2|\3|\4)(\d)(\d)\6{2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VyUNiG/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `5` - a `5` char
- `(\d)` - a digit captured into Group 1 (`\1`)
- `(?!\1)(\d)` - a digit (captured into Group 2) that is not the same digit as captured into Group 1
- `(?!\1|\2)(\d)` - a digit (captured into Group 3) that is not the same digit as captured into Group 1 and 2
- `(?!\1|\2|\3)(\d)` - a digit (captured into Group 4) that is not the same digit as captured into Group 1, 2 and 3
- `(?!\1|\2|\3|\4)(\d)` - a digit (captured into Group 5) that is not the same digit as captured into Group 1, 2, 3 and 4
- `(\d)` - a digit captured into Group 6
- `\6{2}` - two digits that are captured into Group 6
- `$`  - end of string.

Comment: Any idea why the pattern won't match numbers like this one `534252111` although it ends with 3 similar digits?

Comment: @Leena Because `C` != `E` and you have `2` for both in that number.

Comment: Can you add another regex to include this number? Thanks

Comment: @Leena It would violate the "*4 different numbers ABCDE*" requirement. Here, C=2 and E=2. What is the rule here then? `2` is an exception? Or can `C` equal `E`? If yes, use [`^5(\d)(?!\1)(\d)(?!\1|\2)(\d)(?!\1|\2|\3)(\d)(?!\1|\2|\4)(\d)(\d)\6{2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/VyUNiG/3).

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
^5(?:(\d)(?!\d*\1\d*\d{3}$)){5}(\d)\2\2$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lwa9cI/1)

---

- `^5` - Start-line anchor followed by a literal '5';
- `?:(\d)(?!\d*\1\d*\d{3}$)){5}` - 5 Times a non-capture group to match a 1st capture group of a single digit that is not followed by 0+ digits and a representation of itself before the last three digits and the end-line anchor;
- `(\d)\2\2` - A 2nd capture group to match a single digit and twice a representation of itself;
- `$` - End-line anchor.

Comment: ++ but you can do this in a single lookahead as well: `^5(?:(\d)(?!\d*\1\d*\d{3}$)){5}(\d)\2\2$`

Comment: @anubhava, right. Clever mind, the lookahead is not needed. Answer ammended.

Comment: Any idea why the pattern won't match numbers like this one `534252111` although it ends with 3 similar digits?

Comment: @Leena: `534252111` has digit `2` repeating

Comment: @Leena, assuming you thought about your conditions I really don't understand why you are asking this when `ABCDE` should represent 5 different numbers (assuming the 4 in OP is a typo).